# Why the presence of required attribute in option tag affect the color of option text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put a grey placeholder in the select boxes of my form.
It works well when select is required, but when the required attribute is not present he becomes black.

So I would like to have a not required select box with a grey placeholder

Possibly I would like a pure CSS solution.

You can also check from the page where the form is: www.dabosstournament.com

Here a snippet of my form.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0;
}

select:invalid {
  color: #c7c7c7;
}
```

```html
<select required>
    <option hidden disabled selected value="">I mus be not required</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option hidden disabled selected value="">I must be grey</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's quite simple: replace `select:invalid` with `select`

Comment: I suggest using proper HTML, otherwise it's difficult to answer your question as different web browsers may interpret your HTML differently.

Comment: @ChrisG I need when I select an option, to be black

Comment: I don't see how a pure CSS solution would work, as it would require a selection based on the value. A JS solution is straightforward: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lonmkdvp/